# Why is $3^{\log_2 n}$ the same as $n^{\log_2 3}$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I am reading about divide and conquer algorithm at following link on page on 57 in [this link](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL630/all.pdf). The document analyzes the running time of the algorithm. At the very top level, when $k = 0$, this works out to $O(n)$. At the bottom, when $k = \log_2 n$, it is $O(3^{\log_2 n})$, which, the author claims, can be rewritten as $O(n^{\log_2 3})$.

My question is:

> Why can $O(3^{\log_2 n})$ be rewritten as $O(n^{\log_2 3})$?

Comment: This seems to be a question about pure mathematics, not computer science.

Answer (score 6):

The two expressions are equal: $3^{\log_2 n} = n^{\log_2 3}$. To see this, you can use the following identities: $\log_a b = \log_c b/\log_c a$, $\log_a b = 1/\log_b a$, and $a^{\log_a b} = b$. Using these identities, we get
$$
3^{\log_2 n} = 3^{\log_3 n / \log_3 2} = 3^{\log_3 n \cdot \log_2 3} = (3^{\log_3 n})^{\log_2 3} = n^{\log_2 3}.
$$

Comment: Another way of seeing this that I find easier to understand is to use the identities $2^{a \cdot b} = (2^a)^b$ and $x = 2^{\log_2(x)}$: $3^{\log_2 n} = 2^{\log_2(3^{\log_2 n})} = 2^{{\log_2 n} \cdot \log_2(3)} = (2^{\log_2 n})^{\log_2(3)} = n^{\log_2 3}$.

Answer (score 0):

We will use the following facts:

- $2^{\log_2 x}=x$; and
- $\log_2 x^y = y\log_2 x$.

So,

$$\begin{align}
x=3^{\log_2 n} 
&= 2^{\log_2(3^{\log_2 n})}\\
&=2^{(\log_2 n)(\log_2 3)}\\
&=2^{y \log_2 n}\\
&=2^{\log_2 n^y}\\
&=2^{\log_2 (n^{\log_2 3})}\\
&=n^{\log_2 3}.\end{align}$$